# Popup menu onclick at mouse location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, offset

I'm relatively new to coding, so bear with me.  I'm trying to create a menu (for an app) that appears when the user taps and holds on the screen.  Basically I'm looking to make a menu similar to the Pinterest app click and hold menu functionality. (see it here: http://techcrunch.com/2013/07/31/pinterests-mobile-app-gets-path-like-animations-readies-personalization-options/ )

I've found the code to create something similar (http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Animated-Arc-Popup-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html) but I'd like it to appear where the user holds on the screen, not in a fixed location.  I've talked with a professor about this and he suggested using offset(), but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.  The menu would be hidden until the user triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

Some general advice for programming is to break the program down into the smallest logical pieces you can and tackle those little pieces one at a time. a

1. attempt to alert a message upon clicking somewhere on the page, or in your active area
2. then try to create a 100 by 100 black box (div element) anywhere on the page when you click somewhere
3. Then try to get the box to appear where you clicked using the offset as your professor suggested
4. Then change what you previously did to be on mousedown and have another function happen on mouseup to remove that black box.
5. Once you have all that you can style that black box to look like a menu, and have functional buttons on it. You could create/destroy the menu item each time you click, or you could create it once, and toggle it's visibility / position on mousedown / mouseup.

Continue to check your work after every small step to ensure you have no errors. I recommend working in a html file on your local machine, at jsfiddle.net, some javascript editing software (I don't know any), or a combination of those.

Here's some help to get you started https://jsfiddle.net/rz7dayfy/ Click the orange box to try it out.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  xPos = e.clientX - myDiv.offsetLeft;
  yPos = e.clientY - myDiv.offsetTop;
  alert('myDiv clicked at x: ' + xPos + ', y: ' + yPos);
});
```

It creates an event listener on the area in question, sounds like that would be the body of your page. Then it finds the x y coordinates of where that area was clicked. Y axis starts at 0 at the top and increases positively as you go down. X axis starts at 0 on the left and increases positively as you go right. The offset is because jsfiddle creates some padding around your results in the results window.